# Create a custom filter to change the attributes of tag AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

In my webiste there's a functionality where the user can insert a custom tag like this:

```
<font color="#5780CD">Blueish</font>
```

And I have to show it in my AngularJS site and make it show up like this:

```
<font style="color: #5780CD !important">Blueish</font>
```

Currently I'm using `ng-bind-html` to show the tag they inserted, but since there are other styles applied in the webiste as `important` I have to put an `!important` in the inline style.

What I did was create a custom filter like this:

```
angular.
module('SelectPayment').
  filter('specialColor', function($sce) {
    return function(input) {
      var theColor = /"#[0-9a-f]{3,6}"/.exec(input)[0].replace('"', '');
      var output = input.replace(/color="#[0-9a-f]{3,6}"/.exec(input)[0], 'style=\"color: ' + theColor + ' !important\"');
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(output);
    };
});
```

And in my HTML view I have this:

```
<p ng-bind-html="vm.CustomDescription | specialColor"></p>
```

But this isn't working and I think my regular expressions might not be the optimal way to do it. Currently the result I'm getting is this:

```
<font style="color: #5780CD" !important"="">Blueish</font>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use exec, you can use a capturing group to match the color in your regex and in the replacement refer to that group using `$1`. Use `/i` to for a case insensitive match.

`color="(#[0-9a-f]{3,6})"`

If the codes can only be either 3 or 6 characters you might use the regex using an alternation in the capturing group:

`color="#([a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{3})"`

```js
let str = '<font color="#5780CD">Blueish</font>';
let output = str.replace(/color="(#[0-9a-f]{3,6})"/i, 'style="color: $1 !important"');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks, your first regex worked. But in the second example I'm not sure why you placed a `\b` and you missed a `"` at the end. But that example didn't worked when it had the `\b`

Comment: @pnadalini You are right, that `\b` must be a double quote. I have updated my answer.